# java JFreechart update right click options

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

I am creating a GUI that reads and plots information being received from a serial port.  I am trying to simplify the job of the user.  The reading and plotting is working correctly, however, where I am running into problems is easily allowing the user to change the range of the y-axis.  I know this can be done but right clicking and going through the properties but I am trying to implement a file -> set range option within the JMenu.

My question is, how would I save the user input and have it update the "maximum range value" within the chart properties.  Thanks for any help.

I also tried a get/set approach but it would only set the maximum y value at the beginning when the chart was first created and it wouldn't change the value if the user changed the range.  The code below is how I tried to implement the get/set approach.

```
public JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
    JFreeChart result = ChartFactory
            .createTimeSeriesChart("Keyence LS-5001", "Time", "Value",
                    dataset, false, true, false);
    final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis axis2 = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis2 = plot.getDomainAxis();

    axis2.setAutoRange(true);
    axis2.setFixedAutoRange((XYRange.getXmax())); 
    axis2 = plot.getRangeAxis();
    axis2.setRange(0.0, XYRange.getYmax());
    return result;
```

Comment: What axis do you want to set the range to? To the X axis or the Y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are modifying the axis you want. JFreeChart normally uses the domain axis for representing X and the range axis to represent Y (a more through comment about this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904663/624341)). Once identified, simply call its setRange method. Do not set any autorange for the axis.

Comment: I believe I am modifying the axis currently (at least the graph shows it properly).  The createChart method is only called when the program is started.  The graph is updated within a Swing Worker.  How can I call the setRange method within the swing worker?

Comment: @user2755399: You need to call it from the SwingWorker's done() method, that is the method that runs in the event thread.

Comment: if I call it in the done() method will it only update the axis range when the SwingWorker is completed?

Comment: Yes, that is. But if you call it from do() it wall call the method from a thread different than the Event Thread, and can result in odd behaviour.

Comment: I am a relative beginner to java programming so this may be a basic questions.  The GUI and swingWorker are in different classes but the same .java file.  How do I update the axis2.setRange method within the done() method?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: That depends in your classes. If none of them is a static class (the one where the SwingWorker is and the one where axis is), you can access it directly. If any of them is static, you'll need to provide to that class with a reference to the axis.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, it has helped.  Hopefully, this will be my last question.  Regarding the swingWorker, I noticed that I could call the done() method by either using SwingTest.cancel(true) or SwingTest.done().  The only difference was that the done() continued to run the doInBackground() and process() method while the SwingTest.cancel(true) stopped the two methods.  Why is this?

Comment: @user2755399: If you call cancel, SwingWorker will cancel the execution of the task, while calling done waits for the task to be completed. I recommend you to read the Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: I will.  I am trying to update the length of the x-axis using the setFixedAutoRange(), however when I call the set method I created it doesn't update.  The y-axis set method was designed the same and works fine.